# The difference between returning a object/primitive and just simply calling it

Tags: java, string, getter

Recently, I've noticed a ton of people doing things like:

```
class One {
    public static final String anything = "Hi!";

    public static String getAnything(){
        return anything;
    }
}

class Two { // This is not an inner class
    System.out.println(One.getAnything());
}
```

Vs

```
class One {
    public static final String anything = "Hi!";
}

class Two {
    System.out.println(One.anything);
}
```

Is there any more benefit to each one? And which one do you guys think is better?

Comment: Your code is invalid, which makes it harder to tell what we're meant to be comparing. Please give *meaningful* examples when asking questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `anything` is `static final` (as in your example), then there is no difference.

However, using the `getAnything()` method allows the functionality to be changed without having to refactor code.  For instance, logging could be added inside the `getAnything()` implementation.

If you implement a `getAnything()` method, it would be conventional to change the visibility of `anything` from `public` to `private`.

Comment: It's as simple as @Alison writes. There's a little overhead in the method call but you can change the way `anything` is calculated later without changing the calling java code. I also prefer the Getters and Setters, especially as you can let Eclipse generate them for you.

Comment: Also, using getters/setters allows you to easily make a variable readable, but not writable(not particularily important here as he has a public field)

Answer (score 0):

IMHO,There is no difference.Both are serving for the same purpose.

But a small difference will be

```
public static String getAnything(){
       //Hey someone taking value of anything.Do something here.
        return anything;
    }
```

Which is not possible to track if you use

```
  System.out.println(One.anything);
```

If there is need not to do anything,I prefer to write `One.anything` which is clean to read.